# What are the most number of propellors that a rotorcraft has been flown with?

Tags: propeller, rotorcraft

If you had 1000 small propellors you could accelerate upwards many times faster than with 4 large propellors.

What are the rotorcraft experiments with the most number of propellors ever?

Comment: "If you had 1000 small propellors you could accelerate upwards many times faster than with 4 large propellors." Could you, though?

Comment: As @egid said, this number would need to be supported by a reference. The answer is probably in the [Guinness book](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgUfOR46Q48), but you may search in the direction of [hover-board](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/119415/20151224/this-real-life-hoverboard-costs-20-000-and-stays-up-in-the-air-for-six-minutes.htm). However this is going to vary with payload weight, distance flown, altitude, etc. And nothing forbids to stick two boards together to double the record.

Comment: In a related matter, i was searching for references regarding walnut breaking competitions, guinness is a serious reference clearly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4BuThlqA7I

Comment: "If you had 1000 small propellors you could accelerate upwards many times faster than with 4 large propellors." Not with the same total disk area and installed power. One big rotor is always the best.

Answer (score 2):

[This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffb_F7Agqv4) is actually flying with 76 rotors.

But I might argue that your "more rotors is faster" idea may be flawed, smaller propellers are less efficient (because the further from the center you are, the faster the blade is moving, if I'm not mistaken), so the trade may be fewer, more efficient, propellers for a larger number of less efficient ones.

Comment: your point is correct in part, however a long blade with a faster tip will get close to the speed of sound more quickly, so you probably have a limit here...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have come across there was a guy who had mentioned of working with [36 motors on a multirotor](http://diydrones.com/m/discussion?id=705844%3ATopic%3A743321).